# How can we secure a Google Default Credentials file?

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-web-app-service, google-authentication

We're looking at using Google BigQuery to store some data, sent from a ReactJS web client.

[This BigQuery node.js client library guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) says to create the service account key, place the file on your web server, then set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable, which points to the location of the file.

Now, if the file is on the web server:

1. What is stopping someone from downloading that file on the web server, putting it on their own server and doing the same code?
2. How is this secure? Can i lock down the origin somehow to be limited to my domain, or what's the best practice here?

The web server is on Azure App Service, and ideally i would like to lock down access to the application server itself (e.g the code running there), or the JS code (so the origin, via CORS).

3. My guess is the intention here is to place the keyfile *outside* the web server, so it can't be directly served by it?
4. How does that work for PaaS solutions like Azure App Service where i can't do that?

Thanks

Comment: why the "too broad" downvote? I thought this question was pretty simple/specific?

Comment: I did not down-voted you, but could be useful if you specify better in what kind of web server you intend to store the key file and somehow lock down the origin, so I can provide a more specific answer to your questions.

Comment: @RubénC. good point +1. Edited

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to protect the servers and the Microsoft server you are using will have it's own specific protections. I can detail the more general ones.

The web server is usually only accessible through ports 80/8080 for HTTP/HTTPS *requests*. This *requests* generate an answer containing an HTML and all the other stuff you make public.

All the information available for a non-administrator of the service, stored in the server, is protected by the [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(networking)) method. Despite being on the same server, it is not possible to access it remotely. You can think in a building with several floors and apartments. You just have the key for one of them, and so you cannot enter to the others. Answering question 3: no, you are supposed to store the information in the same server.

Regarding question 4, I am with Google Cloud Platform. I don't know how Microsoft manages security, but you can read [this documentation to have a first approach into Google Cloud Platform security](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview). This is not related to networking security, but is what someone using Client Libraries for BigQuery needs.

And if you are interested:

1. Information must be moved between the servers and users. Read [here](https://tiptopsecurity.com/how-does-https-work-rsa-encryption-explained/) how this works.
2. There are lots of security models. You can find [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Services_Architecture_and_Security) an interesting reading (with nice diagrams) about them.